# How to display zero in place of error in filter formula in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google spreadsheet functions and trying to apply a formula in following way:

I have `sheet1` & `sheet2` in one workbook (name-formula4). I am doing sumproduct of filtered range from `sheet1` to `sheet2` with the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(filter(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$401, (Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401>= E1) * (Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401<= E2)))
```

Formula is perfectly ok when the range selected
`(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401>= E1) * (Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401<= E2)`
has some value & is not empty. However if I leave the cells of said range empty (`sheet1!b1:b3`) -which are required to meet criteria- then this gives the error `No Matches are found in filter evaluation`. In a nut shell, I want to display `0` rather than displaying the error or `NA`.

Note that I cannot fill entire the selected `B` column since this receives live data from the form and not previous decided which one.

Please look at the following link for details and help in correcting the above formula:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HTXf4VG2JupiP9UqCLRyAddYjhsom1leQOI9-DwfMaY/edit#gid=0

Comment: Cant you use =IFERROR function to convert your error to 0?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(filter(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$401, (Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401>= E1) * (Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401<= E2))),0)
```

Comment: Please answer following question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431786/extract-two-words-from-a-cell-in-to-another-cell-in-google-spreadsheet

Comment: for the french users, the function is `SIERREUR`, very weird ! Half of the functions are translated only :O

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same issue with my sheets too. I agree with the comments above hiding the error isn't best practice. However hiding the N/A response / customising it is very useful! You need to wrap the whole logic in a NA statement so it starts with it first. Here is how you can do something like this with the formula you are using.

```
=IFNA(SUMPRODUCT(FILTER((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$401,
     (Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401>= E1)*(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401<= E2))),
     "input text or response you want here")
```

Change "input text or response you want here" to what you want to respond. If you just want it to return a numerical value, like `0`, you can remove the quotes at the end and the text response and just put the number. Don't forget the comma (**`,`**) after the bracket though!
It should look like this:

```
=IFNA(SUMPRODUCT(FILTER((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$401,
       (Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401>= E1)*(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$401<= E2))),0)
```

Comment: `IFNA()` was made to get around this error, and is the correct solution.

Answer (score 6):

I do NOT recommend IFERROR because it will suppress all type of errors. And that is not a good practice.

What you should be doing is...

IF the filter returns 0 items, THEN just display 0

ELSE, display sum of all the items.

```
=IF(COUNT(FILTER(_range_,_condition_)) = 0, 0, SUM(FILTER(_range_,_condition_)))
```

Comment: I tried this, and COUNT on an empty FILTER result returns 0. Presumably it is SUM on an empty FILTER result that causes problems, to me this seem wrong, the sum of no elements is 0.
So Mohsin's solution works, thanks :)